# redisgraph create edge between nodes if not exist already in high traffic

Tags: redis, cypher, graph-theory, redisgraph

I have the following cypher query.

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR {id: 'Charlie'})
MATCH (m:MOVIE {id: 'TwoAndAHalfMen'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[e:ACTED {prop1: val1}]->(m)
 WITH COUNT(e) AS c, a, m
 WHERE c=0 CREATE (a)-[:ACTED {prop1: val1, prop2: '<cur-time>' }]->(m)
```

We have an `actor` node and a `movie` node. If there is no edge between the `actor` and the `movie` nodes, then a new edge `ACTED` should be created, with some edge properties.

The above query works fine in an idle database with not much traffic, often responding in less than 1 millisecond. However, when there is a lot of traffic, this particular query alone takes a long time, in the order of multiple seconds. While the other queries finish fine.

I suspect that the reason for the slowness is the `COUNT` function is trying to take all the nodes and somehow gets delayed when there are constant writes. I may be wrong here and just making an assumption.

I do not need to know the total number of edges, and is interested to know only if the edge is there or not. So I tried to do this query in a different way as:

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR {id: 'Charlie'})
MATCH (m:MOVIE {id: 'TwoAndAHalfMen'})
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  MATCH (a)-[e:ACTED {prop1: val1}]->(m)
) 
CREATE (a)-[:ACTED {prop1: val1, prop2: '<cur-time>' }]->(m)
```

But for this I get an error from the `redisgraph` as:

```
RedisGraph does not currently support map projection
```

Is there any other way to optimally create an edge between two nodes if one does not exist already ? I cannot use a `MERGE` command because the `prop2` that I set will be a different value, when I have to create a new edge.

Please note that this should work in redisgraph and not enough if it works on neo4j or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [RedisGraph Merge docs](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/commands/#merge) more specifically `ON MATCH` and `ON CREATE`

e.g.

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR {id: 'Charlie'}), 
      (m:MOVIE {id: 'TwoAndAHalfMen'}) 
MERGE (a)-[e:ACTED {prop1: val1}]->(m) 
ON CREATE SET e.prop2 = 'cur-time'
```

Comment: Thanks. This does simplify the original query. On hindsight, I wonder how I missed this as I have done it in many places. But unfortunately even this query is taking a long time in high traffic. May be the Go library that I use is to blame. In insights it finishes in 1millisecond (internal time) but takes 100ms or so with the go client. Rest of the queries are fast though. Need to profile them better.

Comment: see what GRAPH.PROFILE reports
https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/commands/#graphprofile

Comment: Thanks. The query works fine and finishes in <1msec in zero load. But when we have a lot of writes, it takes even 1 second to respond. The rest of the queries seem to work fine. This is the only query which has edge properties for us and I am not sure if that matters.

Comment: RedisGraph differentiate between two types of queries read-only (queries that do not modify the graph in any way) and write (queries that has the potential to modify the underline graph) we can run multiple read queries concurrently but we can't do the same for writes, as such when the server is under heavy write load expect latency to rise.